# c# role based login

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010

I am working on a project that i want to use role based login.
Ite a really simple project and not for external use at all.
Its just a proof of concept.
What i had thought about was using a page redirect to an admin page in the page load event.
I know this is kinda not the most efficient coding.
This redirect would be based upon critera in the DB.
I have set a field to "Admin" and if this condition is met then it would redirect to an admin page.
So i tried the code below and it doenst work correctly.
Any help/input would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (Session["New"] != null) 
        {
            lblWelcom.Text += Session["New"].ToString();

            if (Session["New"] != null)
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ShowUsersConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                conn.Open();
                string checkAdmin = "select count(*) from Staff where Admin='" + "Admin" + "'";
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkAdmin, conn);


                Response.Redirect("Register.aspx");  //this is the admin page


                conn.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("profile.aspx");  //this is the non admin page
            }

        }
        else

            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");



    }
    protected void btnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["New"] = null;
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work correctly". *How* doesn't it work correctly? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? What have you tried already to fix this?

Comment: I tried using this to run a query against an admin field in the database. What i want to happen is that once a user logs in and creates a session then the session is checked against the db to see if they are admin, if they are it will redirect them to another page.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
int RowsCount = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar());
if(RowsCount > 0)
      Response.Redirect("Register.aspx");
```

**Suggestion :** You need to change your table column name from `Admin` to `UserRole` or something which is more readable.

Comment: It directs all users to the register page, here is te code.

Comment: if (Session["New"] != null) 
        {
            lblWelcom.Text += Session["New"].ToString();

            if (Session["New"] != null)
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ShowUsersConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                conn.Open();
                string checkAdmin = "select count(*) from Staff where Admin='" + "Admin" + "'";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkAdmin, conn);
int RowsCount = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar());
if (RowsCount > 0)
  Response.Redirect("AdminProfile.aspx");
conn.Close();

Comment: The problem is that page always allows acess to the restricted page